# Alternative to iframe for giving purchaser information and allowing purchaser to input whether item was bought on another website?

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

I need some help and out-of-the-box thinking, because I'm genuinely stumped.

I'm making a gift registry website (like for wedding registries). The idea is that the person making the gift registry can add items from anywhere on the web (say, target.com). Then, when someone wants to buy them an item off the registry, they come to our website, find an item, click on the link and are taken to the product page (on target.com) and buy the gift.

The problem is that we need to know if the product was actually purchased so the gift isn't purchased multiple times. Also, we need to give the purchaser the address of the person for whom they're buying a gift.

Here's what we'd like to do:

[image]

Unfortunately, the only way I can think of how to do this is through an iframe, which doesn't work with many large retailers (like Amazon and Wal-Mart), which have blocked iframes for legitimate security reasons. Another option is opening two new browser windows, but that's just ugly.

So, what else can I do? Any brilliant JavaScript/css/php or whatever solutions out there?

Answer (score 0):

you can't reliably detect if an item was purchased if it can be any shop in the web. you can only detect if somone clicked a link to the item in the shop but not if he buys it.
you should rely on the user to mark the item as bought.

Comment: I totally agree -- check out the image for what we'd like to do. The problem is that we'd like to have a clean way to (1) give the purchaser the address of where to send the gift and (2) let the purchaser mark "yes I bought this" or "no, I didn't buy this." But I can't figure out a way to do this other than an iframe.

Comment: well, if you want your part of the page to be visible while the user buys the item you can only use an iframe. CSRF would be another soloution but this would have to be implemented differently for  each shop out there and is propably not working for all shops as they may be protected agains CSRF

Comment: So there's literally nothing else I can do? You'd think that there'd be a solution for this that (a) wouldn't potentially compromise Amazon and Wal-Mart's security but (b) allowed me to put a div on top of their website in a clean way.

Comment: @jake There is literally no way - outside of some possibly obscure and illegitimate security hole that would soon get closed - that you can access any information or have any impact on the 3rd party site without A.) The 3rd party site's explicit cooperation or B.) Asking the user to install a bookmarklet, add-on, extension, etc. There is of course proxying, but then the site wouldn't really 3rd party anymore, and it would be borderline illegal, and 100% inadvisable.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option, albeit a poor one, is a Bookmarklet. The buyer would have to add/install the bookmarklet before they began shopping. After they complete an order they would have to run the bookmarklet on the order confirmation/receipt page to "verify" the purchase.

You would have to write code for every merchant you support. Anytime the merchant changes their confirmation/receipt page you would have to update your verification script. The bookmarklet would determine the merchant from the page URL and check the page for specific elements to determine which product was purchased.

I would use the bookmarklet as an optional step since you can't assume your users will remember to use it or even know how to use it. I would mark items as "Unverified Purchase" when they choose a product from your list, then mark it as a "Verified Purchase" if the bookmarklet is used. You can also make your bookmarklet verification work on "order history" pages for users who forget to use the bookmarklet during the checkout process but still wish to verify their order.